# how to connect Quickbooks and Ruby On Rails?

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, quickbooks

I'm trying to use [qbwc gem](https://github.com/skryl/qbwc) my RoR app to connect to the standard Quickbooks with QuickBook Web Connector.

I have deployed my app on Heroku. when I try to load the qbc file I get the following error:

```
QBWC1048: QuickBooks Web Connector could not verify the web application server certificate
```

I'm using Heroku default domain which according to the Heroku documentation it serves https.

What am I missing?
What is the best approach to solve this?

Comment: What's the URL you're using?

Comment: @evanx did you get this sorted out? I am having the same issue

Comment: Hi thermite, no, I was not able to connect them.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Heroku default domain name e.g. https://yourappname.herokuapp.com.

If you are attempting to use a custom domain name you must [configure an SSL Endpoint on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-endpoint).

The QuickBooks Web Connector wants a valid SSL cert.